# Not able to access any controls via mouse move with JAWS screen reader

Tags: java, jaws-screen-reader

JAWS not working in below scenario

1. Install JRE 64-Bit
2. "Enable Window Access Bridge" from control panel
3. Uninstall JRE 64-Bit
4. Install JRE 64-Bit
5. "EnableWindow Access Bridge" from control panel

I follow above step and JAWS not able to access any controls via mouse move.
I also try with below application.It is not working.
**JavaMonkey-64.exe
JavaFerret-64.exe**

Is there any mistake in above step? Or suggest the right step.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario steps 3 to 5 should not be required and should have no effect on the outcome.

Everything Jaws reads in a Java application is passed through the Java Access Bridge.

If the Java application is not created using classes that are compatible with the Access Bridge then you will get no output from Jaws.

Java Ferret and Java Monkey also read their output from the Access Bridge and not directly from the application.
No output in Java Ferret means that the application is likely incompatible with the Access Bridge.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across to similar issue/question while checking how to enable the support for a assistive technology.

Here is what is required:
 - Java Access Bridge is included JRE 7u6 and later. Make sure you have installed and enabled same or upper version. Install both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the JRE.
- Java Access Bridge is not enabled by default. Enable it.
- After enabling Java Access Bridge, you **must restart** your **assistive technology software** and **Java applications** that use the accessibility API.

How to enable Java Access Bridge:

*Go to Start > Control Panel > Ease of Access > Ease of Access Center. Alternatively, press Windows logo key+u to access the Ease of Access Center.
Select Use the computer without a display.
In the section Other programs installed, select the check box Enable Java Access Bridge (you may have to scroll down).*